# Page Numbering when binding multiple rdlc reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, page-numbering

I am trying to bind multiple rdlc reports into one pdf file, however when using the expression:

```vb
="Page " & Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages"
```

It doesn't sync/continue to use the page numbering, for each new rdlc it breaks and starts the page numbering again. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "bind into one pdf file"? You have a master report with multiple subreports?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Globals.OverallPageNumber and  Globals.OverallTotalPages?